# Assigning data that get returned from a package to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Let's say I have this working code:

```
const myPackage = require('myPackage');
myPackage.internal_func(parameter).then(console.log);
```

This returns a JSON, let's say:

```
{
    a: 'valA',
    b: 'valB'
}
```

What if I want only the value of `a` to be assigned to a variable?

I tried this:

```
const myPackage = require('myPackage');
var data = myPackage.internal_func(parameter).a;
console.log(data);
```

Unfortunately, this returns:

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

If `myPackage.internal_func(parameter)` returns a promise then you need to either use [async/await](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) or chain the function with then().

Using Then()

```
const myPackage = require('myPackage');
myPackage.internal_func(parameter).then(data => {
   console.log(data.a);
});
```

Using async/await

```
const async = require('async');
const myPackage = require('myPackage');
const testFunction = async function(){
  var data = await myPackage.internal_func(parameter);
  console.log(data.a);
}
```

If you are using this code within a function do not forget to include async in the function declaration.

Comment: agh... I wish StackOverflow will let you know that someone answered while I'm typing my answer...

Comment: Thanks but oi got this error: " await is only valid in async function"

Comment: As i said in the answer,  you should add async in the function declaration.

Comment: Example: `const testFunction = async function(){ //use await here}`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in your example `internal_func` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), that's why it doesn't have an `a` property.

Here a few options:

```js
// Async/await
(async function(){
  const parameter = {}; //some param
  const myPackage = require('myPackage');
  const { a } = await myPackage.internal_func(parameter);
  console.log(a);
})();
```

```js
// Thenable
const parameter = {}; //some param
const myPackage = require('myPackage');
myPackage.internal_func(parameter).then(({a})=>{
  // you can use variable a in the code below
  console.log(a);
  
  // some code...
});
```